# TextView spannable text Click detect while clicking email, phone and Web

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I want to display dialog when user click on `TextView` content having phone number, email and URL, According to user selection we have to perform default action of `Spannable` Text or refuse to perform default action.

```
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/text_view"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:autoLink="all"  
android:text="Here is link. https://www.google.com, Phone number 1-80012-12122 and email abc@xyz.com" />
```

Comment: you want a separate dialog foreach part of Spannable text?

Comment: I need same dialog but need to perform default action e.g. If phone then go to dial number

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine your Spannable string with Linkify which is a filter that converts phone numbers, emails, urls, etc.

```
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.TextView );
    Spannable spannable = (Spannable)textView.getText();
    StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan( Typeface.BOLD );
    spannable.setSpan( boldSpan, 41, 52, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );
    TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.TextView2 );
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder( "Here's a smiley, and here's a link http://blablabla.com" );
    Bitmap smiley = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.emoticon );
    ssb.setSpan( new ImageSpan( smiley ), 16, 17, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );
    textView2.setText( ssb, BufferType.SPANNABLE );
    Linkify.addLinks( textView2, Linkify.WEB_URLS );
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** This solution works for me.

Get Data set in TextView as `CharSequence` and convert it into `SpannableStringBuilder`

```
    tvPost.setText(data.getPost());

    CharSequence charSequence = tvPost.getText();
    SpannableStringBuilder sp = new SpannableStringBuilder(charSequence);

    ClickableSpan[] spans = sp.getSpans(0, charSequence.length(), ClickableSpan.class);
    for (ClickableSpan span : spans) {
        int start = sp.getSpanStart(span);
        int end = sp.getSpanEnd(span);
        AutoSpan mySpan = new AutoSpan(String.valueOf(charSequence.subSequence(start, end)));
        sp.setSpan(mySpan, sp.getSpanStart(span),
                sp.getSpanEnd(span), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    }

    tvPost.setText(sp);
    tvPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isAutoLink) {
                DialogHelper.showExternalLinkAlert(context, null, "My Message", spanText.toString());
            }
            isAutoLink = false;
        }
    });
```

Create SubClass within your Activity/Fragment/Adapter where ever you need to apply

```
private boolean isAutoLink = false;
private static String spanText = "";

private class AutoSpan extends ClickableSpan {

    private String autoLinkData;

    public AutoSpan(String autoLinkData) {

        super();
        this.autoLinkData = autoLinkData;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {

        isAutoLink = true;
        spanText = autoLinkData;
    }

}
```

Implement Dialog to display your information

```
public static void showAutoLinkAlert(final Context context, String title, String message, final String autoLink) {
    AlertDialog mExitDialog;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AlertDialogStyle);
    if (title != null)
        builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent;
            if (android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(autoLink).matches()) {
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", autoLink, null));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } else if (Patterns.PHONE.matcher(autoLink).matches()) {
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + autoLink));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } else if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(autoLink).matches()) {
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(autoLink));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    mExitDialog = builder.create();
    mExitDialog.show();
}
```